# Reference frame doubts about isotropy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Landau & Lifshitz on p.5 in their "Mechanics" book states the following:

> ...a frame of reference can always be chosen in which space is
> homogeneous and isotropic and time is homogeneous. This is called an inertial frame.

In Newtonian mechanics, ground frame is almost considered inertial, but we know that in ground frame, space is not isotropic (preferred direction due to gravity). So Landau's statement actually seems wrong if we consider Newtonian mechanics.

In General Relativity, ground frame is non-inertial and free fall frame is inertial in which we know that space is really isotropic - landau's statement holds true.

Even in newtonian mechanics, some inertial frames space can still be isotropic/homogeneous, but since we found even one example where it's not - i.e ground frame, then landau's statement can't be true in general for newtonian mechanics. i.e - when a statement is made, it must either be true in all cases or statement is false.

I think, Landau makes his statement in General Relativity, but nowhere, he mentions general relativity. The statement I copied is taken from his chapter of Galillean Relativity. **What's your opinions on what he meant ? Should I also be thinking in terms of General relativity and not newtonian ?**

Comment: Where did you read that "in inertial frame, space is isotropic"? Also, space being isotropic is a vague statement. What is actually usually meant, and thus is better explicitly said, is that rotating the system around any line going through the center of the coordinate system does not change value of the Lagrangian. This need not be true in inertial frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite correct that the ground frame is not inertial, or at least in General Relativity we would say it is an accelerating frame.

However in Newtonian mechanics we can say it is an inertial frame with gravitational forces acting. That is, we can say the ball accelerates downwards because there is a gravitational force acting on it not because the ground frame is non-inertial. By contrast Einstein would say the ground frame is non-inertial and the *gravitational force* is a fictitious force due to the non-inertial frame.

This is a slightly subtle point. Imagine starting with the observer floating in space far from any masses - we would all agree this is an inertial frame. Now tie the observer's feet to an extended spring so the spring starts to accelerate the observer. Clearly the frame is still inertial but we have an external force due to the spring. If we move the observer a small distance $y$ there would be a potential energy change of $Fy$, where $F$ is the tension in the spring, but this doesn't make the frame non-inertial. That PE change is the change in the PE of the spring.

In a similar way we could start floating in space then bring the Earth towards the observer until the surface of the Earth is just below the observer. Newton would say that just as in my previous example we have not done anything to the "space". We have just applied an external force because the Earth is now pulling on the observer just like the spring. So space itself is still an inertial frame but there are external forces acting. The potential energy change $mgy$ when we move the observer distance $y$ towards the Earth is the change in the energy stored in the Earth's gravitational field.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Though, I want to confirm something and ask it maybe in a clearer way: If in newtonian mechanics, we say ground frame is an inertial frame, then how does the "inertial frames are isotropic" obeyed ? because clearly, $mgy$ is not isotropic.

Comment: The space itself can still be considered isotropic. The gravitational force in classical mechanics doesn't arise from an anisotropy of space, but rather from stuff (i.e. earth) within that space. This is very different from the treatment chosen in GR, where space(-time) itself is distorted due to massive objects.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze I have extended my answer to try and address the question in your comment.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think, before I read it in deep thoughts, i found a mistake (not sure)in your answer. you say:"So space itself is still a non-inertial frame but there are external forces acting." - shouldn't you have said that space is inertial ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze Oops, yes, that's a typo. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ok, I re-read it now. the problem that I have in my mind is the following. We treat ground frame as inertial, we also know that in that frame, space is NON-isotropic, which clearly contradicts what Landau said about inertial frame being isotropic. What's your thought on this ?

Comment: You and Landau mean different things by _space_ and that's what is causing the confusion. You are taking space to mean everything including the gravitational field field and Landau is taking it to be what's left if we remove the gravitational field. That is Landau is treating the gravitational force as an external force like the springs in my example. There is no real difference here - it's a matter of terminology.

Comment: When we say that ground frame is inertial, we don't take gravitational field out of that frame, right ? so in that frame, space consists of gravitational field. no ? because if we take gravitational field out of that frame, then it's not "ground" frame anymore :D

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. Landau's opinion is different from yours. I have to say that I agree with Landau. I would say the space is inertial but there is an external force acting.

Comment: I agree that space is inertial and external force is acting. but space is also non-isotropic and that's where I see the landau's contradiction. I'm not saying that space is non-inertial or anything. contradiction comes about isotropy where landau says that in inertial frame, space is isotropic.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze it's the external force that's anisotropic, not the space that the force acts in.

Comment: I think what landau means by "space" is ALWAYS empty space then - i.e without its constituent members and for sure, in such empty space, we got inertial frame and isotropy too.  Should I follow Landau in that sense that when "space" is mentioned in terms of "homogeneity/isotropy", I should always treat space as empty one ? Problem with this approach is that in Barbara Ryden's book, she says that on small scale, universe is non-isotropic and uses gravity example. (see https://ibb.co/TrrsBYS). Though, she mentions "universe" and not "space".

Comment: My final assumption is that by universe, we mean everything(space + every "body" included in the space) while by space, Landau means empty space(no "body" included in it). Wouldn't you agree ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze Yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the above-mentioned statement in L-L's book takes place in the first volume thus regarding **classical mechanics**.

Even if I dislike Landau-Lifschitz' approach, the requirements of homegeneity and isotropy of the space **uniquely** determine the inertial reference frames in classical mechanics.

That is because

(a) inertial forces are both homogeneous and isotropic **only** in those reference frames, as they vanish there;

(b)  the remaining general dynamical laws are **already** homogeneous and isotropic in the inertial reference frames.

Homogeneity and isotropy of space in dynamics means the  following in practice.

Consider an **isolated** (sufficiently far from the other bodies of the universe) mechanical system made of an arbitrary number of interacting bodies.

Prepare it with some initial conditions and record the dynamical evolution of the parties of the system with a fixed camera.

Next prepare a similar experiment with initial conditions **translated** (homogeneity) and/or **rotated** (isotropy) and perform the same action on the position of the camera.

Finally, compare the recorded movies: it turns out that **you cannot distinguish them**.

This happens **only in inertial reference frames**. If you try to do the same in **non-inertial ones**, you get different movies even if the dynamical systems are identical (including the interactions). That is  because the **apparent forces** act differently in different places of the space (translated and/or rotated with respect to the initial ones).

Inertial reference frames posses also a further property: **time homogeneity**. The practical explanation is similar to the one above just considering translations in time.

Finally there is a further invariance property related to the boost translations, but it changes the (inertial) reference frame.

(As is well known, each of these (3+3+1+3=10 scalar) symmetries implies the existence of a corresponding (scalar) dynamically conserved quantity. But this is another story.)

Earth's frame is not inertial so that it is not a problem.

Passing to more modern formulations, like special and general relativity, the issue becomes much more delicate in view of the notion of rest frame with an observer which should deserve a deeper discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I understand the definition of homogeneity/isotropy, but if ground frame is inertial(in newtonian, which we know it is), how is space in it isotropic ? we know it's not isotropic. i don't know how landau's statement holds true in newtonian mechanics. maybe i misunderstood your answer :(

Comment: What do you mean for "ground frames"?

Comment: you, being on earth's surface(as you're currently). in newtonian, it's considered inertial frame, but if you conduct experiments, you will see that space to you is non-isotropic

Comment: Well it is false: earth's surface does not define an inertial frame at all.

Comment: so, ground frame is not "inertial frame" even in newtonian mechanics ?

Comment: Certainly! I don't understand why you think the contrary.

Comment: In newtonian mechanics, the way I understand "inertial frame" definition is if you can explain the mechanics without fictitious forces, then it's an inertial frame. if you're on ground and observe an accelerating frame where pendulum is hung, to you, you can explain its behaviours without fictitious forces. That's why it's inertial frame. Not only that,  see John Rennie's answer on this question below which says: "However in Newtonian mechanics we can say it is an inertial frame with gravitational forces acting"

Comment: An inertial frame is a reference frame where any body, sufficiently far from the other bodies of the universe, appears to have a motion with constant (possibly zero) velocity. It is a theoretical notion evidently.

Comment: Why does John say that in newtonian, ground frame is inertial ? :)

Comment: I do not know, ask him! :)  Maybe Newton wrote it, but that notion has changed and improved several times in the history of physics. In particular by Mach and other people.

Comment: He is not the first though, I always heard that in newtonian, earth frame is almost considered inertial :P let me wait for his answer.

Comment: ALMOST does not mean that IT IS. A reference frame at rest with the centre of sun and axes oriented according to the "fixed stars" is a much better approximation for instance.

Comment: even in newtonian, if you consider ground frame as non-inertial, then his statement is not false in which case the statement holds true in any inertial frame(whether it's GR or newtonian or whatever). In this case, since earth is non-inertial, it's true it's non-isotropic, but that doesn't make landau's statement false as he is talking about inertial frames while earth frame is not. This is all clear. I will confirm some details though

Answer (score 0):

Landau's statement does not apply in General Relativity. But it is valid in both **classical, in the sense of nonrelativistic** mechanics and in **Special Relativity**.

Moreover even in General Relativity I know that there is a notion of "**local inertial** frame" but it is a bit complicated (for me, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Even though Rennie and Moretti's answers cover most of the issues connected to this question, I would like to address it more directly, eliminating possible misunderstandings from the beginning.

First, the volume's perspective on mechanics is classical mechanics. No general relativity anticipation was intended.

Second, the *ground* reference frame, i.e., the reference frame of a laboratory on Earth's surface, is *approximately* inertial, but not exactly. Deviations from the expected behavior do not depend directly on the presence of gravity but on Earth's motion. If the Earth were not rotating and not revolving around a star in a galaxy, but it was the only planet in the universe, it would behave like an inertial system because a body subject to Earth's gravity plus a compensating force would move with a uniform rectilinear motion. Deviations from the behavior in an inertial reference frame can be detected if the experiments' precision is high enough or the observation time is long enough.

Now, let's go to the Landau- Lifshitz approach. According to the modern view of mechanical phenomena, it is challenging to state Newton's laws satisfactorily.

The main difficulty is in the intertwined role played by the concepts of reference frame, mass, and force. Notice that in Newton's original perspective, the situation was different because the role of reference frames was not so important as after Special Relativity, and also because Newton had his concepts of absolute space and absolute time playing indirectly the role of inertial reference frames.

In Classical Mechanics, inertial reference frames play an important role as the only reference systems where accelerations depend only on real interactions between bodies. A possible way of characterizing an inertial frame is then to say that it coincides with a reference frame *far enough* from any other body, such that any single particle motion is on a straight line and uniform. The precise formulation may differ, but the essence is this one.

Such a definition may seem to exclude the surface of a planet, where the motion of particles on which only gravity acts is accelerated. However, this is not a real difficulty. Once we have one inertial reference frame where any external force is reduced below the observation threshold by the large distance from other bodies, we know that infinite other inertial frames differ only by the choice of the origin or by the relative uniform velocity. One of them may coincide with the center of a planet not interacting with other bodies.

Landau$Lifshitz's proposal is within the previously described approach. They only shift the emphasis from the characteristics of the motion of a test body to the symmetry conditions allowing them. Notice that from the physical point of view, any statement about *space* and *time*, to be amenable to observations must be translatable into a statement about the relative positions of physical systems and physical events. Hidden in their formulation is the asymptotic behavior of a body far enough from any interaction source. Again, once one has found at least one of Landau & Lifshitz's inertial reference frames, there is an infinite number of other inertial reference frames close enough to every possible source of interaction.